# Getting a WindowId from a window handle (HWND) without Windows App SDK

Tags: c#, f#, windows-runtime, hwnd, windows-app-sdk

I want to get a [WindowId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.windowid?view=winrt-22621) from a HWND from F# and .NET so I can call other WinRT APIs which want a WindowID. I think this is done in [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/be13859134711a1b1206da484f2f6b8b41feb883/include/wil/cppwinrt_helpers.h#L333-L338):

```cpp
    inline winrt::Windows::UI::WindowId GetWindowIdFromWindow(HWND hwnd)
    {
        ABI::Windows::UI::WindowId abiWindowId;
        winrt::check_hresult(::GetWindowIdFromWindow(hwnd, &abiWindowId));
        return winrt::Windows::UI::WindowId{ abiWindowId.Value };
    }
```

An equivalent function, [Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(IntPtr)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/api-reference/cs-interop-apis/microsoft.ui/microsoft.ui.win32interop.getwindowidfromwindow), is available in [Windows App SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK) however I can't use the SDK from an F# project because the SDK is bundled with WinUI which [does not work with F#](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/740).

The solution I'd like is being able to call some external function [from F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/external-functions) which exchanges my HWND for a WindowId, but I don't know what I'd need to import or call.
 
Possible workarounds are:

- Implement a [bunch](https://github.com/fabulous-dev/FSharp.Maui.WinUICompat/blob/main/src/FSharp.Maui.WinUICompat/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml.cs) of [workarounds](https://github.com/fabulous-dev/FSharp.Maui.WinUICompat/blob/main/src/FSharp.Maui.WinUICompat/FSharp.Maui.WinUICompat.props) to allow referencing Windows App SDK.
- Create a separate C# project which references the Windows App SDK and exposes the Windows App SDK GetWindowIdFromWindow function. (And mark whatever [assets as private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).)

Comment: If the solution is limited to pure win32 API, then you can use P/Invoke to call API functions directly without SDK. You can use csWin32 (https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) source generator to generate P/Invoke declarations.

Comment: Not sure why they created this WindowId thing maybe for (future?) cross platform? Anyway, currently WindowId's value = HWND's value :-) Another way is to use an undocumented function from AppSDK's Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll you can declare like this in C# (don't know in F#) `[DllImport("Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll")] private static extern int Windowing_GetWindowIdFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, out WindowId windowId);` this dll is part of the AppSDK Runtime and always loaded in an WinU3I app

Comment: @SimonMourier, you're right, they're the same. Fun! 
(I tested it using your other suggestion, which also works.)

If you submit this comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious why this [WindowId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowid) concept exists, beyond the fact it's documented for top-level windows only where HWND are for all windows. Maybe for a (future?) cross platform target?

Anyway, currently the WindowId's [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowid.value) is equal to the HWND's value, so it's pretty easy to compute one from another.

Another way is to use an undocumented function from AppSDK's `Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll` file. You can declare this in C# (don't know in F#):

```
[DllImport("Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll")]
private static extern int Windowing_GetWindowIdFromWindow(
    IntPtr hwnd,
    out WindowId windowId);
```

or to avoid linking to WindowId structure:

```
private static extern int Windowing_GetWindowIdFromWindow(
    IntPtr hwnd,
    out ulong windowId); // windowId = hwnd...
```

This dll is part of the AppSDK Runtime and always loaded in an WinU3I app. Maybe overkill...